# C++ POCO HTTPRequest get std::bad_alloc execption all the time

Tags: c++, httprequest, poco

I tried to do a simple Http Request using POCO, but I get a exeption at this line:

```
HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, path, HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
```

and this line if I ignore the previous one:

```
request.add("Authorization", "TokenABC");
```

it said:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD11B1A839 in 
VirtualKeybroadGui.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at 
memory location 0x000000F4B60F82F0.
```

I'm not sure but look like the problem is I am using too much memory. Any way to handle this? The API seems ok because I test it on Postman and it work correctly.
This is my full code:

```
int APIService::GetDevicesAPI()
{
// Create a URI
URI uri("http://222.252.62.94:3123");

// Create a session
HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());

// Set connection to keepalive
session.setKeepAlive(true);

const std::string path = "/device";

// Choose the http request method
HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, path, HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);

// Add headers
request.add("Authorization", "TokenABC");

// Send the request
session.sendRequest(request);

// Receive response
HTTPResponse response;
istream& page = session.receiveResponse(response);

// Store received body
string received = ""; // Store the body in string
string tmp; // Temporary variable
while (getline(page, tmp))    // Loop into each line of page
{
    received += tmp + "\n";     // Insert each line into variable received with endline
}
// Print the stored body
cout << received << endl;
// Now compile the code and open wireshark



return 0;

}
```

Comment: Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. See [ask] for more information. Until you do that, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to figure out your problem.

Comment: I would compile your example in DEBUG mode and then run it under the debugger.  If it crashes it will stop and highlight hopefully the section that messes up with your code.